# How can I set up import so that airflow doesn't show errors whereas the tasks are running properly

Tags: python, airflow

We are developing our ETL on airflow 1.10.6 using cloud composer on GCP. Everything works well but we keep getting error message in the logs and in the interface regarding relative imports unless every tasks are running properly

```
ERROR - Failed to import: /home/airflow/gcs/dags/filepath.py attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Other files with the same architecture and the same imports do not create the same errors. It fails in the `process_file` when running the command `imp.load_source`. If we change to non relative imports it works well also.

Do you have an idea of which file is executed in this `process_file` and how we could solve this error (only in the logging but not in the execution).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So We have found out that airflow for an obscure reason was considering it as a dag and trying to import it as a dag. We have added the folder of this file to `.airflowignore` file and it has solved the issue

Comment: The root folder is usually reserved for dags while modules can be put in subfolders like for example a `dependencies` folder with python modules that then can be imported

Comment: This was helpful.  The reason that this only affects a subset of files is [this optimisation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html):
_When searching for DAGs inside the DAG_FOLDER, Airflow only considers Python files that contain the strings airflow and dag (case-insensitively) as an optimization._